# Can create a subset based on date

Tags: sas

I have the following dataset and code:

```
DATA survey; 
 INPUT id order_date ; 
  DATALINES; 
  1 11JAN2007 
  2 12JAN2007
  3 14JAN2007
; 
PROC PRINT; RUN; 

data work;
set survey;
where '11JAN2007'<= order_date <= '13JAN2007';

proc print data=work;
run;
```

When I run this code it does give the desired output however. It only gives a table with three empty order_date columns.

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: try looking up how to reference dates in SAS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

```
DATA survey; 
informat order_date date9. ;
    INPUT id order_date ; 
    DATALINES; 
    1 11JAN2007 
    2 12JAN2007
    3 14JAN2007
;
RUN; 
PROC PRINT data = survey; 
    format order_date date9.;
RUN; 

data work;
    set survey;
    where '11JAN2007'd<= order_date <= '13JAN2007'd;
run;

proc print data=work;
    format order_date date9.    ;
run;
```

See SAS help for topics date, informat,...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query based on date, you need to tell SAS that your string is a date. You do this by putting a 'd' after the date string, e.g.

```
'11JAN2007'd
```